# Adding Radio Button in Custom Cell of TableView and unable to access outside

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios5, ios4

I am adding Radio Buttons in custom cell of UITableView and calling a method on it to changes its image or background Image. I able to set Selected button Image from sender but I want to make other buttons to their original position which I am unable to set it, as below functionality need to be look like proper Radio buttion in a cell

I am also facing problem in fetching proper Index Path in this method - (void) TableRadioButtonSelection:(id)sender;

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *RadioIdentifier = @"RadioCellIdentifier";

        RadioBtnCell *myRadiocell = (RadioBtnCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:RadioIdentifier];
        if(myRadiocell == nil) {
            [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"RadioBtnCell" owner:self options:nil];
            myRadiocell = radioCell;

            //[myRadiocell.radioBtn1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radiobtn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            myRadiocell.radioBtn1.tag = ButtonTag;
            //[myRadiocell.radioBtn2 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radiobtn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
             myRadiocell.radioBtn2.tag = ButtonTag1;
            //[myRadiocell.radioBtn3 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radiobtn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
             myRadiocell.radioBtn3.tag = ButtonTag2;
            myRadiocell.tag = RadioTag;

            [myRadiocell.radioBtn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(TableRadioButtonSelection:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [myRadiocell.radioBtn2 addTarget:self action:@selector(TableRadioButtonSelection:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [myRadiocell.radioBtn3 addTarget:self action:@selector(TableRadioButtonSelection:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

            myRadiocell.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            self.radioCell = nil;

        }

return  myRadiocell;

}

- (void) TableRadioButtonSelection:(id)sender {

    //RadioBtnCell *buttonCell = (RadioBtnCell*)[[btn superview] superview];

    RadioBtnCell *cell = (RadioBtnCell *)[self.questionTblView viewWithTag:RadioTag];
    UIButton *mybtn = (UIButton *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:ButtonTag];
    UIButton *mybtn1 = (UIButton *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:ButtonTag1];
    UIButton *mybtn2 = (UIButton *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:ButtonTag2];

    [mybtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radiobtn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [mybtn1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radiobtn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [mybtn2 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radiobtn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

     //NSLog(@"%@",[cell subviews]);
    UIView* mysubview = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:ButtonTag]; // Make sure your UITextField really *is* the last object you added.
    UIView* mysubview1 = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:ButtonTag1];
    UIView* mysubview2 = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:ButtonTag2];

   // I am unable to set Image of other buttons apart from sender.

    //for(UIView *item in [mysubview subviews]) {

        if ([mysubview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
            UIButton *newBtn = (UIButton*)mysubview;
            UIButton *newBtn1 = (UIButton*)mysubview1;
            UIButton *newBtn2 = (UIButton*)mysubview2;

            NSLog(@"OK %@",newBtn);
            //[newBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radiobtn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [newBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radiobtn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [newBtn1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radiobtn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [newBtn2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radiobtn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        }
    //}

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.questionTblView indexPathForCell:cell]; 
    NSLog(@"%d",indexPath.row);

    //  Below code is setting Image of selected Button properly as checked but above code for making button onto original state is not setting button image or background image

    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
    [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radiobtn_chk.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    //[btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radiobtn_chk.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing this line to this;-

```
RadioBtnCell *cell = (RadioBtnCell *)[self.questionTblView viewWithTag:RadioTag];

to

     RadioBtnCell *cell = (RadioBtnCell *)[self.questionTblView cellForRowAtIndexPath:*indexPathofthecell*];
```

In this way you can access the table view cell.After that you can get the button from cell content views and do further coding.

Suppose if you do not know the indexPath then you can create the indexPath fromm the rowNumber of the table view(I think you have stored the table row number in RadioTag, if yes so you can use this field as a parameter).